# String.Format Is it possible to display file name for Path string in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string.format

Hi i am new to C# and WPF. The below is just example not tested.

Lets say i have

```
String path1 = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\File.ext"
String path2 = "C:\temp\text.txt"

String.Format(path1.Substring(path1.LastIndexOf('\')+1))
String.Format(path2.Substring(path1.LastIndexOf('\')+1))
```

I want to get the filename from the path without changing the original string and i want to do it preferably in XAML or do a value converter.

I am looking into this to know if I should do a value converter between one Observable collection and ListView or just stick with two Lists. One to contain filepaths in model manually and fileNames to display in a ListView and update both separately (Current approach).

My data model

```
private List<String> AttachedFiles;
public ObservableCollection<String> fileNames { get; set; }

    public void addFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.AttachedFiles.Add(filePath);
    }

    public void removeFilePath(String filePath)
    {
        this.AttachedFiles.Remove(filePath);
    }
```

The xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="DropList" ItemsSource="{Binding fileNames}"
```

I included very little code as this as to give an just an idea as I am thinking of refactoring. Can i use String methods inside String.Format for dipsplaying in XAML so it will still have the original filepath value in the model or is there some syntax for String.Format to do this?

EDIT
The answers are duplicated but I was asking if String.Format can be used in the XAML converter with methods like Trim Substring Etc and if I should refactor my code, but doing it properly creates more code and complexity than it removes.

EDIT 2
This is the code. Basically the list view has an X icon and text with file name next it, if the user clicks the icon the it will call this:

```
    private void r1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle r = sender as Rectangle;
        ticket.removeFilePath(r.DataContext.ToString());
        ticket.fileNames.Remove(r.DataContext.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: See the marked duplicate for working code to show only the file name. There are many ways to approach the problem. If you feel the marked duplicate doesn't address your question, post a new question that includes a good [mcve] showing clearly what you've tried, and explain _specifically_ what it is you're having trouble getting to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one collection, and don't use `List<T>`:

```
ObservableCollection<String> FilePaths { get; private set; }
```

If you replace the collection, you'll need to raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`.

Write a value converter (OK, just steal mine):

```
public class FileName : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use the value converter in a `DataTemplate`. Since `FilePaths` is a collection of `String`, the `DataContext` of your `DataTemplate` will be a `String`, so the binding won't specify a property for the binding to use. The value passed to the value converter will be the string itself.

```
<ListView x:Name="DropList" ItemsSource="{Binding FilePaths}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label 
                Content="{Binding Converter={local:FileName}}" 
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work, the exemel is giving an erro that it expects the IValueConverter type The xaml is:    <Label Content="{Binding Converter={local:Ticket}}" Padding="5,5,5,5" />

Comment: @RobertMazurowski What does the class definition for local:Ticket look like?

Comment: It is this class MyModel : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter, INotifyPropertyChanged. My class contructor is creating the list: public myModel() {
            this.fileNames = new ObservableCollection<String>();
        }

Comment: @RobertMazurowski Why would you implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Try removing that. I've written a lot of value converters this way and never had an issue.

Comment: @RobertMazurowski wait, wait: was that a class named Ticket? Or MyModel? What does Ticket look like? Which one gave you the error?

Comment: The class was ticket, i forgot that i have showed the name. I should not show code outside of work:( Because the model class has a several other fields which are binded to other controls, The class has the interface and implements the methods so i fought this is not the issue. I come from Java:) Does this mean that I need to make the converter and file list a seprate class in C#?

Comment: @RobertMazurowski This is getting too weird for me. No idea what you're trying to do, sounds crazy, can't possibly help you fix it. My example works. Just follow it and you're fine. You used Ticket in the XAML you showed me, not MyModel. The converter must implement IValueConverter. The error says it doesn't.

Comment: @RobertMazurowski Don't use your model as a value converter. There's no reason to. If you need to give it multiple parameters use a MultiBinding with IMultiValueConverter.

Comment: Sorry for that I cannot show code used at work and I asked so many questions recently that i got lost in my "Abstract substitions". It is MyModel is just abstract of the ticket class, I have there 3 strings which are attached to notify property changed and this one list of fileNames. If I leave the fileNames in ticket class and make a separate value converter class what would i have to change in your converter and XAML?

Comment: @RobertMazurowski You would use my converter and XAML just the way I wrote them. In your viewmodel, you would have a property  `public ObservableCollection<String> FilePaths { get {...} set {...} }` with the usual INotifyPropertyChanged stuff. That collection will contain the full complete paths. My converter takes a path and returns just the file name part of the path. If you're using Java-style casing everywhere, you may as call it `filePaths` for consistency.

Comment: Thank very much as soon as I will test this I will let you know how it works. Because there is also a function that deletes a file from the list when user clicks on an icon inside the list view so hopefully it will convert back:)

Comment: @RobertMazurowski How are you deleting the path from the collection?

Comment: I have edited the questions with this method

Comment: @RobertMazurowski I would expect that to work for removing the file path, IF and only if `sender` is actually a `Rectangle` and its `DataContext` is actually the path. Obviously it will fail to remove the filename from the filenames collection, because the DataContext there is the whole path, not the filename. But I don't know why you still have a filenames collection at all.

Comment: @RobertMazurowski Wait, is `removeFilePath` still what you quote in your question? If it is, of course nothing will work at all. I worry that you still have the filenames collection around. That should be gone, almost certainly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with only one property here, you can just use a converter as other answer suggested. But you could also create a new Class for your `Path` object, and define a `FilePath` string property in this class to store the full path. (And more properties if you need.)

Then you can just override the `ToString` method in this Class to return just the `filename`.

By doing this, you don't need to change the XAML, but the binding list will just display the item as the result returned by your override `ToString` method.

Something like:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyPath> fileNames { get; set; }


public class MyPath: ObservableObject  //implement INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _filepath;        
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return _filepath; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _filepath)
            {
                _filepath= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FilePath");
            }
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
    }
}
```